# Joins are coming back with no rows selected

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i'm having some trouble with trying to extract some data from several MySQL tables in a join statement.

My tables and attributes are:

```
    appointment_end_time (table)
    appointment_end_time_id (int)(pk)(ai)
    appointment_end_date (datetime)

    appointment_start_time (table)
    appointment_date_id (int)(pk)(ai)
    appointment_start_date (datetime)

    instructor(table)
    instructor_id (int)(pk)(ai)
    firstname varchar(45)
    lastname varchar(45)

    appointment_timetable
    appointment_timetable_id int(11) AI PK 
    instructor_id int(11) FK
    appointment_date_id int(11) FK 
    appointment_end_time_id int(11) FK
```

```
SELECT a.appointment_timetable_id,  i.instructor_id, ad.appointment_start_date, aet.appointment_end_date
FROM db12405956.appointment_timetable a
JOIN instructor i on i.instructor_id = a.instructor_id
JOIN appointment_start_time ad on ad.appointment_date_id =  a.appointment_date_id
JOIN appointment_end_time aet on aet.appointment_end_time_id = a.appointment_end_time_id
ORDER BY a.appointment_timetable_id;
```

However, this code brings back no rows selected when executed so i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong, any help will be much appreciated

Sample rows:
                           (appointment_end_time)

```
     appointment_end_time_id  appointment_end_date
                  1            2016-12-26 14:00:00
                  2            2016-12-24 13:00:00
                  3            2016-12-26 13:00:00
                       (appointment_start_time)

     appointment_date_id  appointment_start_date
                  1            2016-12-26 15:00:00
                  2            2016-12-24 16:00:00
                  3            2016-12-26 15:30:00

     instructor_id      firstname       lastname

           1              Sasha         Thompson

           2              Laura         Robinson

           3              John          Walters

                         appointment_timetable


appointment_timetable_id instructor_id appointment_date_id appointment_end_time_

        1               Blank             Blank                Blank 

        2               Blank             Blank                Blank  

        3               Blank             Blank                Blank
```

Comment: Show enough sample data to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: It means one or more of your tables lacks the data to make the relationship work. You have appoinments that lack instructors, or start_times, or end_times, so you get nothing back. It's impossible to say though since this is a data issue and you have not shown any.

Comment: @JNevill so for example I have 9 instructors and 3 start times and end times, does that count to anything? Does the amount of rows need to match one another?

Comment: @m.cru please show 3 sample rows from each table

Comment: @m.cru What it means is that you need to have an `instructure_id` that is common to both `appointment_timetable` and `instructor` table. You also have to have a `appointment_date_id` that is common to your `appointment_timetable` and your `appointment_start_time` table. Is one a time/datetime type and the other a date type? The same will be true for your `appointment_end_time`. The number of records in each table is not important, just that each table has data for the join condition to be true. If any are false, you get no data.

Comment: @JNevill the datatypes are all the same and the columns match one another

Comment: Change your joins to left joins and see if you get any results.

Comment: You need to either change your `blanks` in each column in your `appointment_timetable` to match the `appointment_id` or you need to change every `ON` clause for each JOIN to join on the `appointment_id` to each table's respective `ID`. Like `JOIN instructor i on i.instructor_id = a.appointment_id` You see... you have BLANKS for your `instructor_id` on your `appointment_timetable` table, so the join you have written will fail as `BLANK <> 1, 2, or 3`

Comment: @m.cru what's up with the **Blank**s? how are you hoping to link the tables?

Comment: @MisterPositive, That is dangerous advice, you should only use left joins if the requirement indicates the need for them not just because you played with them. If you don't know your data model well enough to understand if a left join is necessary due to the business rules, then you have no business querying the database at all. BUT NEVER USE LEFT JOINS WILLY NILLY.

Comment: Its a comment @HLGEM, not the answer.  The point of the comment was to perhaps shed some light to the OP as to why not results are being return as the OP expects.  I would agree with your comment if I posted this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to learn how to diagnose the problem yourself. It is a common problem that a query doesn't return the expected results and you should understand how to break things down to find the issue.

Let's start with your query:

```
SELECT a.appointment_timetable_id,  i.instructor_id, ad.appointment_start_date, aet.appointment_end_date
FROM db12405956.appointment_timetable a
JOIN instructor i on i.instructor_id = a.instructor_id
JOIN appointment_start_time ad on ad.appointment_date_id =  a.appointment_date_id
JOIN appointment_end_time aet on aet.appointment_end_time_id = a.appointment_end_time_id
ORDER BY a.appointment_timetable_id;
```

What you do to break it down is start with the first table and then add the joins (and where conditions although you don't have any here), one at a time until the data problem appears. I find this easiest to do by using select * or select top 1 * (Or top 10 as I usually prefer to see more than one record) instead of the field list because then you don't have to look for the fields that are associated with joins you haven't added in yet.

So start with

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM db12405956.appointment_timetable a
```

Then try

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM db12405956.appointment_timetable a
JOIN instructor i on i.instructor_id = a.instructor_id
```

Then

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM db12405956.appointment_timetable a
JOIN instructor i on i.instructor_id = a.instructor_id
JOIN appointment_start_time ad on ad.appointment_date_id =  a.appointment_date_id
```

Finally

```
SELECT top 10 *
FROM db12405956.appointment_timetable a
JOIN instructor i on i.instructor_id = a.instructor_id
JOIN appointment_start_time ad on ad.appointment_date_id =  a.appointment_date_id
JOIN appointment_end_time aet on aet.appointment_end_time_id = a.appointment_end_time_id
ORDER BY a.appointment_timetable_id;
```

At some point you will see where the records fell out and that is the location of the problem. Then you might need to look at the fields you are joining on and the data in them in your data sets to see why they are not returning any matches. For instance, if you are joining on dates, they may be stored as dates in one table and as varchar in another and date "01/01/2016' is not equal to 'Jan 1, 2016' or sometimes the column has some sort of prefix or suffix not in the other table. Something like PR2345 in one table and 2345 in the other. Sometimes the query is correct and no rows genuinely meet the conditions. This could be because the data is not fully populated yet (think writing a report for a system that is not live yet, no data on completed actions because none have completed yet.) or because the requirement was wrong in some of its assumptions or because there should be no matching records. It could even be a bug in the data entry.

Depending on the nature of the problem, you might need to return all the records or only use select top 1 (since all records are disappearing). Using SELECT * this way will help when you are returning too many or duplicate records as well as sometimes is is the fields not being returning that affect the results set. **Note that I am not saying to use SELECT * in your final result set, it is only being used as a diagnostic tool here.**

In your case, the problem looks as if it is in the first table. There are blanks for instructor ID and the other fields in your sample, so there is nothing to join on. (You only gave a sample so the rest of the table may not be like this.) If this is a case where the data is not there yet due to the feature that would add it not yet being live, then you can test your query only by adding test data to the table. Be sure to delete this data after you have finished unit testing.  If the data should have been there, then you need to look at the insert from the application for a bug.